# How to get image file from local directory by gatsby-transformer-asciidoc?

Tags: gatsby, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I use [gatsby-transformer-asciidoc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-asciidoc/) and write `image::<some-name>[]` in `.adoc`. But I haven't could get images.

**Dirctory structure**

```
---images
 |  |-cheetah.png
 |-posts
 |  |-test.adoc
 |-src
 |-gatsby-config.js
 |-gatsby-node.js
 :
```

**gatsby-config.js plugin**

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-asciidoc`,
    options: {
      attributes: {
        imagesdir: `/images`,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

**test.adoc**

```
 :
image::cheetah.png[]
 :
```

But I haven't get the image.

And I test an another plugin strucure.

**gatsby-config.js**

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-asciidoc`,
    options: {
      attributes: {
        imagesdir: `${__dirname}/images`,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

But I could not.

**Please save me!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, maybe not the better one but it works for me.

You can put your images in a `static/images` folder at the root of your project, that way, you can use the default `imagesdir` attribute and it will work.

Meaning your directory structure would be

```
 |-static
 |  |-images
 |    |-cheetah.png
 |-posts
 |  |-test.adoc
 |-src
 |-gatsby-config.js
 |-gatsby-node.js
 :
```

and your config

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-asciidoc`,
    options: {
      attributes: {},
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks! It moving!
I overlooked gatsby static folder.
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/